# Create custom view made out of other custom views

Tags: java, android, xml, android-custom-view, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create a custom view that is formed of other custom views. These views extend the View class. The custom view I'm trying to create is the title of the game, which is currently available on iOS, and it's made out of 8 NodeViews, one for each letter of the game title, Word Flow.

I'd like the TitleView custom view to be flexible in that I can define the size of it using attrs.xml, so it's possible to have different versions of it for different screen densities.

The main problem I'm facing is: How do I properly position these NodeViews in the TitleView?
Here is what the TitleView looks like:

[image: 1]

Here is my code for the NodeView class:

```
package com.limeshift.wordflow;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class NodeView extends View {

    int nodeColour;
    String nodeText;
    Paint backgroundPaint = new Paint();
    Paint textPaint = new Paint();

    public NodeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.NodeView,
                0, 0);

        try {
            nodeText = a.getString(R.styleable.NodeView_nodeText);
            nodeColour = a.getColor(R.styleable.NodeView_nodeColour, 0);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }


    public int getNodeColour() {
        return nodeColour;
    }

    public void setNodeColour(int colour) {
        nodeColour = colour;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    public String getNodeText() {
        return nodeText;
    }

    public void setNodeText(String text) {
        nodeText = text;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int w, int h) {
        super.onMeasure(w, h);

        w = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.title_node_size);
        h = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.title_node_size);

        setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //NodeView background
        backgroundPaint.setColor(getNodeColour());
        backgroundPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawCircle(getMeasuredWidth() / 2, getMeasuredHeight() / 2, getMeasuredHeight() / 2, backgroundPaint);

        //NodeView text
        textPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/dosis_centered.ttf");
        textPaint.setTypeface(tf);

        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.title_node_text_size));
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

        int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2);
        int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent()) / 2));

        canvas.drawText(getNodeText(), xPos, yPos, textPaint);
    }
}
```

It uses two custom XML properties using the < declare-styleable > tag.
The NodeView right now is just a basic circle, with the colour passed in from the XML layout for the menu activity, and the letter, which uses a custom font.

In iOS it's possible to define absolute positions of everything, making creating a title like this quite straight-forward, whereas the closest I got to this on Android is RelativeLayout, which allows me to position the NodeViews using margins and by stating how the nodes are positioned relative to each other or the parent. That isn't very practical though.

I'd really like it if I could specify the center positions of the nodes.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What are you using for the base class of TitleView, which I'm guessing is parent view for each of the nodes.

Comment: It's just extending View, though I don't think that's the right View to extend in this case.

Answer (score 0):

your TitleView should lay out NodeViews, you can do it by extending ViewGroup and overriding onLayout

Comment: How exactly would I do that?

Comment: Seems interesting, though how should I add the NodeViews children to the TitleView? I'm guessing `NodeView node1 = New Node()` is a start, but I'm not sure what to do about the context parameter.